# Update Slider Gallery to jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Does anyone know how update the following code to jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.5.3?

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
    body {
        padding: 0; 
        font: 1em "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, sans-serif; 
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: #212121;
        margin: 0;
    }

    h1 { 
        margin-bottom: 2px; 
    }

    #container {
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 580px;
        margin: 15px auto;
        padding: 50px;
    }

    /* slider specific CSS */
    .sliderGallery {
        background: url(http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/productbrowser_background_20070622.jpg) no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        height: 160px;
        width: 560px;
    }

    .sliderGallery UL {
        position: absolute;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .sliderGallery UL LI {
        display: inline;
    }

    .slider {
        width: 542px;
        height: 17px;
        margin-top: 140px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        padding: 1px;
        position: relative;
        background: url(http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/productbrowser_scrollbar_20070622.png) no-repeat;
    }

    .handle {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: move;
        height: 17px;
        width: 181px;
        top: 0;
        background: url(http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/productbrowser_scroller_20080115.png) no-repeat;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .slider span {
        color: #bbb;
        font-size: 80%;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 110;
        top: 3px;
    }

    .slider .slider-lbl1 {
        left: 50px;
    }

    .slider .slider-lbl2 {
        left: 107px;
    }

    .slider .slider-lbl3 {
        left: 156px;
    }

    .slider .slider-lbl4 {
        left: 280px;
    }

    .slider .slider-lbl5 {
        left: 455px;
    }
-->
</style>
```

Javascipt:

```
<script src="jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-full-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.onload = function () {
        var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
        var ul = $('ul', container);

        var itemsWidth = ul.innerWidth() - container.outerWidth();

        $('.slider', container).slider({
            min: 0,
            max: itemsWidth,
            handle: '.handle',
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                ul.animate({'left' : ui.value * -1}, 500);
            },
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                ul.css('left', ui.value * -1);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Divs:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Slider Gallery</h1>
    <p>This shows a demonstration of a slider widget from the jQuery UI library used to create the same effect used on <a href="http://www.apple.com/mac/">Apple's web site</a>.</p>
    <p><a href="/slider-gallery">Read the article, and see the screencast this demonstration relates to</a></p>

    <div class="sliderGallery">
        <ul>
            <li><img class="pb-airportexpress" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_airport_express.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_airport_extreme.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_timecapsule_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_keyboards20070807.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_mighty_mouse.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_cinema_display20071026.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_mac_pro_20070622.jpg" /></li>

            <li><img class="pb-macmini" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_mac_mini.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_macbook20071026.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img class="pb-macbookair" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_macbookair_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img class="pb-macbookpro" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_macbook_pro20071026.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img class="pb-imac" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_imac20071026.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_macosx_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_ilife_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_dot_mac_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_iwork_20080115.jpg" /></li>

            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_quicktime.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_aperture20080212.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_final_cut_studio2_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_final_cut_express_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_logic_studio_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_logic_express_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_shake_20080115.jpg" /></li>                    
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_apple_remote_desktop_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_xserve.jpg" /></li>

            <li><img src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_xserve_raid.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img class="pb-xsan" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_xsan_20080115.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img class="pb-macosxserver" src="http://static.jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/images/pb_macosx_server20071016.jpg" /></li>                    
        </ul>
        <div class="slider">
            <div class="handle"></div>
            <span class="slider-lbl1">Wi-Fi</span>
            <span class="slider-lbl3">Macs</span>
            <span class="slider-lbl4">Applications</span>
            <span class="slider-lbl5">Servers</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any and all help greatly appreciated guys.

Ferdia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI slider scroll bars have changed since UI v1.5.3. The [**latest demo**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll) is probably the best place to start if you are looking for a simple, clean example of how to build a slider scroll bar.

Do you actually want to rebuild the slider gallery exactly as in the [**existing demo**](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/slider-gallery.html) or can you just use a simple CSS `overflow:scroll` as in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DSdgr/) I made.

I have also [**started a solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYFfk/) to rebuild with the old assets but using jQuery 1.5.2 and jQuery UI 1.8.9. It's not complete as I don't want to put effort into rebuilding an old gallery if that is not what you want. Regardless, that should give you a good start if you really want to do that.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Ah, sorry I misunderstood the question. You *have* to use jQuery 1.3.2! Is the UI version flexible at all? You can downgrade to jQuery 1.3.2 and UI 1.7.3 and [**my (updated) demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYFfk/1/) still works.

**Edit 2:** [**Smaller handle height demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GYFfk/2/). For reference I reduced the `height` property on the the following CSS rules:

```
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider { background:none; border:0; height:20px; margin:0 auto;  }
.scroll-bar-wrap .ui-slider-handle { top:.2em; height:10px; }
```

**Edit 3:**

I finally found the information I was looking for to explain why just upgrading to jQuery 1.3.2 and UI 1.5.2 caused the handle to stop working. Those versions were never compatible - see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/1d3926272cac57bf/7458083c9c526ede). Allegedly UI 1.6 was the first to be compatible with jQuery 1.3.2 but UI 1.7.3 is recommended from the [UI download page](http://jqueryui.com/download).

Note that the demo includes a jQuery UI theme but you can use include it like this in your page:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: Hi Andy,

The example given is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, but it doesn't run in 1.3.2, which runs a vast number of other scripts across the site.

Comment: Loving your new example. Now forgive what is possible a totally noobish question (I am a good PHP coder, but with Javascript i still have my training wheels on, lol), can the handle the user grabs be made to be smaller? (height wise)

Comment: Yes, the CSS controls the height of the handle. I have updated the answer with a link to a tweaked demo. Note that this still uses the later version of jQuery UI. Are you OK to use UI 1.7.2? I cannot get the slider to work with UI 1.5.3 yet.

Comment: Let me quickly see how my other plugins run with UI 1.7.2

Edit: Funnily enough the only thing that broke was the temporary replacement I patched together before you answer the question XD

Nice job sir!

Comment: This is weird. I have copied everything line for line, but I am not getting the custom scroll bar. Its showing up as though it were an iFrame. (Chrome)

Comment: You need to also include one of the jQuery UI themes - see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348559/are-there-hosted-jquery-ui-themes-anywhere/1349238#1349238) for a list. You should be able to see it is included on the jsFiddle page (under Manage Resources on the left). That is what is currently styling the handle with the light blue color. You can either use a different theme, [roll your own](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) or just use CSS to override the colors to what you need.

Comment: I still can't convince this script to add the custom UI, I'm assuming it doesn't matter that I'm calling UI 1.7.2 but using a theme marked 1.8.13?

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference but you could replace the version for the theme with `1.7.2`. Is the jsFiddle custom scrollbar is displaying OK?

Comment: I cant post the link here, its a private development. Is there any chance we could speak on an IM service so I can show you it? You already got the tick ;)

Comment: Actually I could just move it to another server, lol. http://ferdiaobrien.com/richie/dev/test-space.php

Comment: Sorry, also missed your question. JSFiddle is A-OK yes.

Comment: OK I know what the problem is. In jsFiddle you don't need to wrap the jQuery inside the [`document.ready`](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()) (jsFiddle can do that for you), but on your site you need to wrap all jQuery with `$(function() {` and `});`. So if you edit your `js/apple-style-slider.js` file and add `$(function() {` to the start and `});` at the end, that should fix it. Essentially what you are seeing is the native browser slider without any of the jQuery UI on top :-)

Comment: Ok, we seem to be on to a winner now. Thank you very much Andy, you were a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine in either version, only things i can point out have to do with coding style and not with the jQuery version like:

```
var ul = $('div.sliderGallery ul');
```

instead of:

```
var container = $('div.sliderGallery');
var ul = $('ul', container);
```

Comment: i was saying, you can do `var ul = $('div.sliderGallery ul');` instead of what you have above..

Comment: Ah ok, so the other way around. With either set up running through jQuery 1.3.2 and jQuery UI 1.5.3 the slider wont slide :(